# Deleting Files in Shared Google drive using Apple script

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a shared folder and one of the editor usually add files into it.  I want to keep flushing the folder by the following code by capturing its last change date.  Its throwing error and it seems to me that as i am NOT the owner of the file, i cannot able to delete.  Is there any way out?

```
 function 7DayFlush()

    {

      // Log the files names and its last change info for the mentioned folder (by id)
      // Enter the ID between Bracket

      var mfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('<i keep folder id here>');


      // Following will get files from the folder.  
      var lfiles = mfolder.getFiles();

      while (lfiles.hasNext()) {
        var file = lfiles.next();

        if (new Date() - file.getLastUpdated() > 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {

          //Following will delete the files which matches the above condition which is older than 7days in the specified folder.

          Logger.log(file.getName()+'----'+file.getLastUpdated());

//here is the error comes up.. help me.                    
          file.setTrashed(true);
//here is the error comes up.. help me.

        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have the owner of the file authenticate the application so that you can delete the file?  You cant delete something you don't own or have permission to delete.

Comment: @DaImTo First of of all thanks for the response.  Now i understand that i cannot delete a file which i didnt own, however the shared folder owner is myself.  Thru browser, i am able to delete the files on the folder however i cannot do the same by script.  Hope i am explaining well, else i will record a video and post.